# I just start to learn some unity tutorial and get stuck for some reason

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I just start learn some unity tutorial and get stuck by the error " There is no argument given that corresponds to the required formal parameter 'direction' of 'My_Script.movePlayer(Vector3) "
And I dont know why?

```
public class My_Script : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float speed = 10.0f;//movement speed
    private Rigidbody rb;
    public Vector3 movement;
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        // Keyboard Input
        float x = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
        float y = Input.GetAxis("Jump");
        float z = Input.GetAxis("Vertical");
        movement = new Vector3(x, y, z);
    }

    private void Fixedupdate()
    {
        movePlayer();
    }
    
    void movePlayer(Vector3 direction)
    {
        rb.velocity = direction * speed;
    }
}
```

Comment: try `movePlayer(movement);`

Comment: If I could give you one piece of advice (since you just started today) do some basic c# course somewhere. Although the results will be less engaging like working with unity is. It will help you to understand a c# as a language better

Comment: Adding to @JochemVanHespen 's comment, learning c# basic first then learning unity will be WAY faster than learning unity first and searching for solution when you get stuck at c#.

Comment: Okay, Then I will go though some C# tutorial first, Thanks you so much

Answer (score 3):

Your function `movePlayer(Vector3 direction)` takes a parameter of type vector3, but when you call this function in `FixedUpdate()`, you forgot to give it this parameter. So you should write :

```
private void Fixedupdate()
{
    movePlayer(movement);
}
```

This should solve your problem.

Answer (score -1):

Every function which is non-parameterless accepts an argument.

So you will have to pass a Vector3 value inside the movePlayer function, like this:

```
movePlayer(movement) or something else of type Vector3
```